# differences between windows java 1.7 and linux 1.7

Tags: java, linux, windows

I have found a rising number of differences between the current release of 1.7 on windows and 1.7 on linux.  For example Files.ReadAllBytes(Path path) does not exist in Linux (generates compiler error indicating invalid method) as well as us "||"" in a catch phrase so two or more exceptions will process through the the same code.

Does anyone know the extent of the divergence and if it is planned is to stay with different version of functionality for different platforms.

Regards

Theo.

Comment: `Files#readAllBytes` is part of the offical specifications of the language.  It sounds more like you either have the wrong JDK installed or are using the wrong version. Try using `javac -version` at the command line and see what you get.  Also, how are you building your programs on linux?  Command line, IDE some other build process?

Comment: Which distribution you are referring to (Oracle, OpenJDK, IBM etc) ?

Comment: There will not be difference in Windows vs Linux JDK if both of these JDKs are of same version and from Oracle.

Comment: In fact there is very little difference between OpenJDK and the Oracle versions

Answer (score 7):

Since you say that `|` is not supported in `catch` statement, you are very likely to use a JDK 1.6 on linux. Also `Files.ReadAllBytes(Path path)` is part of the public API, so it is available on each platform where the JDK is supported. This method is part of  NIO2 JSR that was added in JDK 1.7, but is not available in JDK 1.6

You can check the version in your path using `java -version` in a shell.